# Using loop to make column selections using different vectors

Tags: r, loops, vector, dataframe, identity-column

Let's say I have 3 vectors (strings of 10):

```
X <- c(1,1,0,1,0, 1,1, 0, NA,NA)
H <- c(0,0,1,0,NA,1,NA,1, 1, 1 )
I <- c(0,0,0,0,0, 1,NA,NA,NA,1 )
```

Data.frame `Y` contains 10 columns and 6 rows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1  0      
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0  0      
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0  1      
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0  0      
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0      
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  1
```

I'd like to use vector X, H en I to make column selections in data.frame Y, using "1's" and "0's" in the vector as selection criterium . 
So the results for vector X using the '1' as selection criterium should be:

```
X <- c(1,1,0,1,0, 1,1, 0, NA,NA)
1 2   4    6 7
0 1   0    1 1
1 1   0    0 1
0 0   0    0 0
1 0   1    1 1
0 0   0    0 1
1 1   1    0 0
```

For vector H using the '1' as selection criterium:

```
H <- c(0,0,1,0,NA,1,NA,1, 1, 1 )
3      6    8  9  10
0      1    0  1  0
1      0    0  0  0
0      0    1  0  1
1      1    1  0  0
0      0    0  0  0
0      0    0  1  1
```

For vector I using the '1' as selection criterium:

```
I <- c(0,0,0,0,0, 1,NA,NA,NA,1 )
6          10
1          0
0          0
0          1
1          0
0          0
0          1
```

For convenience and speed I'd like to use a loop. It might be something like this:

```
all.ones <- lapply[,function(x) x %in% 1]
```

In the outcome (all.ones), the result for each vector should stay separate. For example:

```
X 1,2,4,6,7    
H 3,6,8,9,10
I 6,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is using the `%in%` operator:

```
Y[, X %in% 1]
```

To do this for multiple vectors (assuming you want an *AND* operation):

```
mylist = list(X, H, I, D, E, K)
Y[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(mylist, function(x) x %in% 1))]
```

Comment: First one is splendid! Second one results in an answer of 0 columns and 300.000 rows.

Comment: @EJHendriks if you can come up with a (simple) reproducible example, would be fairly easy to pinpoint the issue

Comment: I tried to describe the question in more detail above.

Comment: @EJHendriks looks like you simply want an 'or' instead of 'and', so just replace & with | and you should be good to go

Comment: Unfortunately, this only results in one outcome string of compiled data. Goal is to get three separate groups of columns, i.e. X 1,2,4,6,7 H 3,6,8,9,10 I 6,10

Comment: @EJHendriks sorry, it's not clear to me what you want - is it perhaps `lapply(mylist, function(x) Y[, x %in% 1])`?

Comment: Second attempt. Hopefully I made my question a little more clear:).

Comment: @EJHendriks I suggest creating an example input/output as if none of the above suggestions work for you I still unfortunately don't know what you want

Comment: Took a while to come up with the next attempt:).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the NA, use `which` to get round it. Consider the following:

```
x <- c(1,0,1,NA)
x[x==1]
[1]  1  1 NA
x[which(x==1)]
[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
idx <- which(X==1)
Y[,idx]
```

EDIT: For six vectors, do

```
idx <- which(X==1 & H==1 & I==1 & D==1 & E==1 & K==1)
Y[,idx]
```

Replace `&` with `|` if you want all columns of Y where at least one of the lists has a 1.

Comment: This works perfect! I'm now trying to do this for six different vectors on dataframe Y using a loop.                             mylist <- list(X,H,I,D,E,K)                                        for(i in mylist){i <- which(i==1 & !is.na(i))}                                                         However, this only gives results for of the last vector K. Any tips?

Comment: In some way this results in 0 columns with 300.000 rows, so the information seems lost in the calculation?